# CakePHP Retrieving data from habtm

Tags: cakephp-2.1, has-and-belongs-to-many

I haven't been able to find a solution that solves this. I am trying to query my database for a list of groups to which a user belongs. Users can be in multiple groups, and groups can have multiple users.

I have "users", "groups", and "groups_users" tables. Each has an "id" field, and the "groups_users" table has two other fields, "group_id" and "user_id".

I think all the tables are properly formed.

My User.php, and Group.php model files look like this

```
//app/Model/User.php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $recursive = 1;
    public @hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'joinTable' => 'groups_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id'
        )
    );
}

//app/Model/Group.php
class Group extends AppModel {
    public $recursive = 1;
    public @hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'groups_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Then, in my Controller file I have this

```
//app/Controller/ProjectController.php
class ProjectController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Groups', 'Users');
    ...
    $this->set('groupsForUser', $this->Groups->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('Users.UserName' => 'testuser1')
    ));
}
```

Every time I try to display the data, I get the error message
**Error: ..... Unknown column 'Users.UserName' in 'where clause'**

And it shows me the SQL it's trying to run:
**SELECT `Groups`.`id`, ... FROM `accounts`.`groups` AS `Groups` WHERE `Users`.`UserName` = 'testuser1'**

Obviously the association between the tables isn't happening properly and the SQL query it is sending in isn't joined properly, but I can't figure out what's going wrong here. I've tried varieties like

```
.....$this->Groups->Users->find(....
```

And stuff like that, but nothing seems to work.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take a completely different approach to the problem. It's mostly "Cake-y".

I simplified the models a bit by taking out the $recursive bit and trimmed down the HABTM part, removing the joinTable, foreignKey, and associationForeignKey bits)

The ProjectController got the code:

```
public $uses = array('Group', 'User');
$arrayGroupsForUser = array();
....
$results = $this->User->Find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('User.UserName' => 'testuser1')
));

foreach($results['Group'] as $result) {
    array_push($arrayGroupsForUser, $result['name']);
}
$this->set('groupsForUser', $arrayGroupsForUser);
```

(Thank you ned stark for noting the need for a singular "User". I can't upvote your answer with my limited reputation yet.)

The "$this->set(.....);" line is to pass just the array of group names to the View to use.

This link http://rottmann.net/2012/07/cakephp-hasandbelongstomany-relationship-queries-demystified/ was a big help in helping me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think You should use "User.UserName" instead of "Users.UserName" in your ProjectController.php because you have "User" in your associations So model name should be same.

```
//app/Controller/ProjectController.php
class ProjectController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Groups', 'User');
    ...
    $this->set('groupsForUser', $this->Groups->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('User.UserName' => 'testuser1')
    ));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I've tried changing that, but to no effect. It changes the SQL query it submits to the MySQL database to be"SELECT Groups.id, ... FROM accounts.groups AS Groups WHERE User.UserName = 'testuser1'"

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I've tried changing that (and the Groups to Group), but to no effect. It changes the SQL query it submits to the MySQL database to be: 
"SELECT Groups.id, ... FROM accounts.groups AS Groups WHERE User.UserName = 'testuser1'"  
  
(note the singular "User.UserName" in the query instead of the plural)  
  
The query itself isn't including the proper JOIN between tables, and so it isn't capable of querying on anything outside the Groups model. There must be something messed up with the join, but I can't figure out what it could be.